# MongoDB update objects that match the query inside an array of an object

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, nosql

I want to update a collection of post and update each comment. How do I do that?

This is a sample:

```
{
    "pid": "kennethlumalicay-ja55nh40ja64br0h",
    ...more_stuff,
    "comments": [
        {
            "uid": "kennethlumalicay-ja55nh40",
            "username": "kennethlumalicay",
            "usertag": "Full Stack",
            "comment": "hey"
        },
        {
            "uid": "kennethlumalicay-ja55nh40",
            "username": "kennethlumalicay",
            "usertag": "Full Stack",
            "comment": "what"
        },
        {
            "uid": "kennethlumalicay-ja55nh40",
            "username": "kennethlumalicay",
            "usertag": "Full Stack",
            "comment": "now"
        }
    ]
}, ...other_posts
```

This is my code:

```
  Post.updateMany({ 'comments.uid': user.uid }
    , { 'comments.$': {
      username: user.username,
      usertag: user.usertag
    }}
    , null
    , () => {
      fetchPosts(null, (posts) => {
        cb({
          posts: posts,
          user: user
        });
      });
    });
```

What I expect:
Find each post that has comments with the uid and update each comment.

```
{
    "pid": "kennethlumalicay-ja55nh40ja64br0h",
    ...more_stuff,
    "comments": [
        {
            "uid": "kennethlumalicay-ja55nh40",
            "username": "kennethlumalicay",
            "usertag": "Front End", // updated
            "comment": "hey"
        },
        {
            "uid": "kennethlumalicay-ja55nh40",
            "username": "kennethlumalicay",
            "usertag": "Front End", // updated
            "comment": "what"
        },
        {
            "uid": "kennethlumalicay-ja55nh40",
            "username": "kennethlumalicay",
            "usertag": "Front End", // updated
            "comment": "now"
        }
    ]
}, ...other_posts
```

What happens instead:
Find each post that has comments with the uid and update one comment and remove other properties.

```
{
    "pid": "kennethlumalicay-ja55nh40ja64br0h",
    ...more_stuff,
    "comments": [
        { // removed uid and comment
            "username": "kennethlumalicay",
            "usertag": "Front End"
        },
        { // nothing
            "uid": "kennethlumalicay-ja55nh40",
            "username": "kennethlumalicay",
            "usertag": "Full Stack",
            "comment": "what"
        },
        { // nothing
            "uid": "kennethlumalicay-ja55nh40",
            "username": "kennethlumalicay",
            "usertag": "Full Stack",
            "comment": "now"
        }
    ]
}, ...other_posts
```

Is this possible to achieve or should I just create another collection of comments and just store the post id?
Or maybe I should just fetch the user data base on uid everytime I'm gonna render the comment? But that doesn't sound great.

Answer (score 0):

Your using "$" operator in "coments.$".

Check out the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/

> $ Acts as a placeholder to update the first element that matches the
>   query condition in an update.

Also, i think you would like to use the $set operator, so u r not overriding the whole "comment" obj with a new object containing only the *username* and *usertag* fields.

try:

```
Post.updateMany({ 'comments.uid': user.uid }
    , { 'comments': $set: {
      username: user.username,
      usertag: user.usertag
    }}
    , null
    , () => {
      fetchPosts(null, (posts) => {
        cb({
          posts: posts,
          user: user
        });
      });
    });
```